# Unable to decrypt PGP encrypted file into Stream from Azure Blob storage using C# scripting within script task of SSIS

Tags: c#, encryption, azure-blob-storage, bouncycastle, pgp

I am trying to read the PGP encrypted file from Azure Blob Storage using SSIS package - Script Task- C# code into Stream, decrypt the file data into string and load to Azure SQL MI server. But I am not able to decrypt the file from Azure blob storage. When if I am reading the PGP encrypted file from Azure blob storage and downloading to the local folder, then from local folder I am able to decrypt the file and store the decrypted data into string.

Below the Main program - ScriptMain.cs

```
  public void Main()
            {
                try
                {
                    #region variables
                     string azureBlob = Dts.Variables["User::vAzureBlobContainer"].Value.ToString();
                    string azureStorageAccessKey = Dts.Variables["User::vAzureStorageAccessKey"].Value.ToString();
                    string azureStorageAccount = Dts.Variables["User::vAzureStorageAccount"].Value.ToString();
    
                  
                    StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentials(azureStorageAccount, azureStorageAccessKey);
    
                    checkPoints = "1. Storage Login";
                    string inputFileName = @"FileInput.csv.pgp";
                    string keyFileName = @"C:\\PrivateKey\\keyfile.asc";
                    string passwd = @"z6yrFkE2NwzX";
                    
                    char[] password1 = passwd.ToCharArray();
                    string output;
                    output= PGPDecrypt.Program.DecryptFile(inputFileName, keyFileName, password1, credentials, azureBlob);
    
                 string[] lines = output.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    
                       int count = 0;
    
                       foreach(string line in lines)
                       {
                           count++;
    
                       }
    
                       int cnt;
                       cnt = count;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Dts.Events.FireError(0, "ERROR", checkPoints + ",\n" + ex.Message, null, 0);
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                    //throw;
                }
            }
```

Note : All required libraries added to ScriptMain.cs

Decrypt.cs

Comment: Please paste the specific error. Please tell me you don’t work for a superannuation fund.

Comment: Hi Nick, Thank you for your reply! I don't work for that. I added output snippet in post. Can you please check on it?

Comment: I probably can’t help you with your problem but unless you copy paste the error (don’t link to pictures) no one one else will be able to either.

Comment: Please check following code line from Decrypter.cs : PgpObject o = pgpF.NextPgpObject();  In this line, I am getting "null" instead of stream if I use above code. Hence value of PgpEncryptedDataList enc is also becoming null. And when it comes to foreachloop due to Null value in enc, script fails object reference issue.  But if I download the .pgp file to local folder from Azure blob storage and read it in stream from local folder then I am getting expected value in PgpObject o. But I don't want to download this file anywhere else from Blob storage.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using SSIS and not something cloud native? Did you already ask a similar question to this already?

Comment: As the source file is PGP encrypted, I'm not much sure whether using cloud native we can decrypt the PGP encrypted file and load to the Azure SQL Managed Instance server table without downloading the file on temporary/local folder. I checked on some other articles and platform as well but couldn't get anything suitable. Please suggest if you have any other way.

Comment: I can tell you that a colleague is doing this exact thing right now (but not with SSIS) but I'm not sure if they managed to work with a stream or whether they had to write to a local file. I'll check and let you know.

Comment: Comparing the Java code we are using and your .Net code (I am an expert in neither), I see very little difference, I imagine you both copy pasted the same demo code. If you are out of ideas I recommend you try it inside an Azure Function as this is a far more suitable platform than .Net inside SSIS

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, I will try that too. With my above code, I am able to find the solution now. I just have to set the stream position to 0 right after writing in stream (mystream.position =0). (I haven't worked on C# earlier, so I was not having the clue to play with streams).

Comment: Oh fantastic to hear you solved it. If you have time you could write a brief answer (including code) and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the OP that the issue has been resolved.

(Posting the findings as an answer so that if someone faced the similar issue in future, he would get the solution on this thread. This will be helpful for other community contributors.)

The issue has been resolved after setting the stream position to `0` right after writing in stream `(mystream.position = 0)`.